# Destroying zfs dataset, migrating data to parent dataset

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have these zfs datasets:

```
pool1
pool1/ds_parent
pool1/ds_parent/ds1
pool1/ds_parent/ds2
pool1/ds_other
```

I want to keep all data which is now contained in the datasets `ds1` and `ds2`, but I don't want `ds1` and `ds2` to be datasets anymore; I just want `ds1` and `ds2` as separate directories within the dataset `ds_parent`. After this, I want this list of zfs datasets:

```
pool1
pool1/ds_parent
pool1/ds_other
```

In other words: All data within dataset `ds1` should be migrated to the directory `ds1`, and all data within dataset `ds2` should be migrated to the directory `ds2`. `ds1` and `ds2` should be destroyed as datasets.

Can this be accomplished quickly and easily without copying/moving files and dirs?

**Version info:**

I'm on Freebsd 10.2-RELEASE. `dmesg | grep -i zfs`

```
ZFS filesystem version: 5
ZFS storage pool version: features support (5000)
```

Comment: I think you're stuck copying.